# parse.com delete too slow for re-render

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, delete-row

I am adding a delete (destroy) object abilities to my web app.
When i destroy the object and then re-render, my table still displays the destroyed line. when i delete again it fails to delete. I looks like my re-render is too fast for the destroy function. How can i re-render after the destroy is complete?

```
function fncBuildEditData(i) {
    var EditData = Parse.Object.extend("WorkOrders");
    var query = new Parse.Query(EditData);
    query.get(i, {
            success: function(myObj) {
                myObj.destroy({});
            },
            error: function(object, error) {
             alert("DELETION FAILED!");
        }
    });
    fncBuildWOTable();//rebuild table
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `query.get` will return instantly, before it runs its `success` function, and likewise the `myObj.destroy` will also return before running it's `success` function. You should perform your reload inside the inner function, like so:

```
function fncBuildEditData(i) {
    var EditData = Parse.Object.extend("WorkOrders");
    var query = new Parse.Query(EditData);
    query.get(i, {
            success: function(myObj) {
                myObj.destroy(
                {
                    success: function(x) { 
                        fncBuildWOTable();//rebuild table
                    },
                    error: function(x, error) {
                        alert("DELETION FAILED!");
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(object, error) {
                alert("GET FAILED!");
            }
    });    
}
```

You have also mentioned that you are using the following code to bind the function:

```
function ClickedRowButton() { 
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteLine', function() {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); 
        //var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text(); 
        //alert(row); 
        fncBuildEditData(row); 
    }); 
}
```

I believe that you were actually attempted to find only the closest element, rather than a collection of elements, so use this instead:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Comment: thanks, that works great on the first Delete. After that it fails and i get two "Deletion Failed!" alerts. next time i get three "Deletion Failed!" alerts.

Comment: It seems like the variables are holding data and trying to delete the objects that it has already deleted. maybe . what do you think?

Comment: i thought this might be where the issues is in my code. Here i code before the code above. 'code' function ClickedRowButton() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteLine', function() {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        //var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
        //alert(row);
        fncBuildEditData(row);
    });
}'code'

Comment: Why not use $('.btnDeleteLine').click(function() {}); also, do you get the correct results from alert(row)? I'm assuming your binding of the click event or the elements that is selects as parent must be at fault, as you are getting it called multiple times. Check alert(row.length) too

Comment: I will change to code for that way and run some tests. Yes the alert(row) displays the row that it is on, same ID multiple times.

Comment: Do you notice a difference between $(this).parents('tr') and $(this).closest('tr') also, may be that that first one is selecting multiple elements?

Comment: That is a good notice. Using Closest works great. Put that as an answer and i will vote it up.